# PayPal PayerInfo address details empty

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to retrieve details of transactions.  I am retrieving details of the transactions (PayerName and the PaymentInfo) but the PayerInfo.Address information as returned by `GetTransactionDetailsResponseType` is empty.  I have tried both live and sandbox.  The `PayerStatus` for all is `unverified` and `AddressStatus` is `Unconfirmed`.  Could this be the issue?  I can understand that the sandbox is like that but not the live system.

The code I use is simplistic but quite long - I will post any sections you ask to see but will refrain from posting the full amount: I do a `TransactionSearch` and then foreach `PaymentTransactionSearchResultType` I pass the `TransactionID` to get the `GetTransactionDetailsResponseType`.  All simple stuff and probably non-optimum (speed is an issue too, but secondary to the main issue of the address).  The code is very similar to the Java versions [here](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-transaction-search-java-1.6/soap) and [here](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-gettransactiondetails-java-1.6/soap).

Any ideas as to why I can get the payment details but no address information about the payer?

Comment: When doing the GetTransactionDetailsRequestType, have you adding the DetailLevel to the request?  (request.DetailLevel.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.RETURNALL);)

Comment: No, I am no adding DetailLevel to the request.  I had to do `Array.Resize(ref concreteRequest.DetailLevel, 1); concreteRequest.DetailLevel[0] = DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll;` but that didn't change anything - still empty data.

Comment: Why the down vote?  If you are going to down vote please comment why.

Comment: Add your code please to enabled better analysis